# Custom button on WP Tiny MCE Posts Editor for Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

Trying to create a special button on the Tiny MCE editor on the Post Editor of Wordpress. I want to create a button for my created shortcode tooltips.

Check out my desired output:

[image]

I have the following code for my Tooltip shortcode:

```
//Text tooltip
function tooltip($atts, $content = ''){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
          'class' => '',
          'title' => ''
        ), $atts);


     $html = '<a class="' . $atts['class'] .'"  title="'. $atts['title']. '" href="#">' . $content . ' <span>' .$atts['title']. '</span> </a>';
    return $html;    
  } 

add_shortcode('tooltip', 'tooltip');
```

Now when you execute this you will use the following codes for the shortcode:

```
[tooltips class="top_tooltip" title="Your Tooltip here"] Text here [/tooltip]
```

What I have done is that created some function to DISPLAY MY CREATED CUSTOM BUTTON TOOLTIP SHORTCODE on the functions.php file on my theme using the following codes.

```
//Create Tiny MCE buttons
function mce_tooltip($button) {
  $buttons[] = 'superscript';
  return $button;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'mce_tooltip');



/*
* Callback function to filter the MCE settings
*/

function mce_tooltip( $init_array ) {  

// Define the style_formats array

  $style_formats = array(  
    // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
    array(  
      'class' => '',  
      'title' => ''      
  );  
  // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
  $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

  return $init_array;  

} 
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_tooltip' );
```

I tried the code but it won't show up my CUSTOM button for my shortcode on the TINY MCE Editor on Wordpress. Any idea how to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code. I guess there is invalid return value

```
function mce_tooltip($button) {
  $buttons[] = 'superscript';
  return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For TinyMCE Advanced Version: 4.1.1 follow this steps:

1. In /wp-content/plugins/tinymce-advanced/tinymce-advanced.php (`function get_all_buttons()`) add `$buttons[] = 'yourButton'`
   http://prntscr.com/5ywb4p
2. In /wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js after some button add your own
   `e.addButton('yourButton',{title:'yourButton',text:"yourButton",'class' : 'yourButton-btn', onclick : function() {  e.focus(); e.selection.setContent('<YourTag>' + e.selection.getContent() + '</YourTag>'); } })`
   http://prntscr.com/5ywc48
   Then go into tinymce settings in wp-admin and add your new button to editor.

Comment: Very bad idea. Editing files that are in `wp-includes` this is definitely wrong way !!!! `wp-includes` is something like the `vendor` directory - that mean, do not modify anything inside !!

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gavick.com/blog/adding-your-own-buttons-in-tinymce-4-editor/

Try this tutorial, it works. It teaches how to add a custom button to the new tinymce 4 and how to use it for your own shortcodes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, there would be a lot to write in order to give you a working version based on your code, that's why i linked the tutorial.. Is a step by step process.